# Temporary tables and table-valued parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a procedure that receives a table as a parameter. I need to fill it on then return it to another procedure that executes the first one. But, the problem is that when y compile I receive this error message:

> *Mens 352, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Procedimiento Person_InsertCloud, Línea 1
>
>   The table-valued parameter "@TableServerIds" must be declared with the READONLY option.*

Can't a table as a parameter can be modified? What other options do I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't a Table as a parameter can be modified?

No. It is one of the restrictions on TVPs.

The restriction is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

> Table-valued parameters must be passed as input READONLY parameters to Transact-SQL routines. You cannot perform DML operations such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT on a table-valued parameter in the body of a routine.

Instead of filling a table, you can *return* a table from your second stored procedure using `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

No the contents of the TVP can't be modified. Upvote [Relax restriction that table parameters must be readonly when SPs call each other](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299296/relax-restriction-that-table-parameters-must-be-readonly-when-sps-call-each-other) if you want this functionality.

The other option is a local `#temp` table. Stored procedures have read and write access to `#temp` tables created in parent scopes. But this does mean that callers of the sub procedure need to be aware of this requirement and create the expected `#temp` table before calling.

An example below

```
CREATE PROC P1
AS
    CREATE TABLE #Foo
      (
         X VARCHAR(50)
      );

    EXEC P2;

    SELECT *
    FROM   #Foo;

GO

CREATE PROC P2
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Foo') IS NULL
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR ('This procedure expects table #Foo to already exist',16,1);

          RETURN;
      END

    INSERT INTO #Foo
    VALUES      ('Inserted by P2')

GO

EXEC P1
```